# distinct does not work properly in with related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 7 app I have users table(id, username), interests(id, name) ad user_interests(user_id, interest_id)
as any user can have different interests.
I need to select other users with similar interests of a given user. I do:

```
$userInterests = UserInterest
    ::getByUserId($user_id)
    ->with('Interest')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get(); // I need given user(user_id) interests

$userInterestIds= [];
foreach( $userInterests as $nextUserInterest ) {
    $userInterestIds[]= $nextUserInterest->interest_id;
} // I get interests ID of given user(user_id) 
\Log::info(  varDump($userInterestIds, ' -1 $userInterestIds::') );

//  
$similarUserInterests = UserInterest
    ::getByInterestId($userInterestIds)
    ->where(with(new UserInterest)->getTable().'.user_id', '!=', $user_id)
    ->with('User')
    ->distinct('user_interests.user_id')
    ->get();
```

the requests above works, but distinct does not work as I expect.
I see traces (given user id = 5):

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `vfrm_user_interests` 
    WHERE `vfrm_user_interests`.`user_id` = '5' 
    ORDER BY `created_at` desc 
  
  
   SELECT * 
    FROM `vfrm_interests` 
    WHERE `vfrm_interests`.`id` in (1, 3, 5) 
  
  
   SELECT distinct * 
    FROM `vfrm_user_interests` 
    WHERE `vfrm_user_interests`.`interest_id` in ('1', '3', '5')     AND `vfrm_user_interests`.`user_id` != '5' 
  
  
   SELECT * 
    FROM `vfrm_users` 
    WHERE `vfrm_users`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

1. Why

   ->distinct('user_interests.user_id')

does not works?

2. If there is a way to sort by number of common interests at top ( given user has
   more common in user_interests) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following can get what you desire

```php
//Get the user with the given $user_id with interests
$user = User::with('interests:id')->findOrFail($user_id);

//Pluck the ids of interests
$ids = $user->interests->pluck('id');

//Get other users with similar interests
//Ordered in descending order based on number of common interests
$usersWithSimilarInterests = User::withCount('interests')
    ->whereHas('interests', function($query) use($ids) {
        return $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
    })
    ->orderBy('interests_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```